# String was not recognized as valid Date Time

Tags: c#

The following code throws an error 'String was not recognized as valid Date Time'.

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";
string timeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, null);
```

How to convert that text field to a DateTime?

I assigned the date time string to a variable just for clarification. In my scenario, The date string comes from a datetimepicker control.

Comment: What is the date in words that you are looking for?

Comment: @Ash Is there a doubt about which is the day, and which is the month? ;)

Comment: Your date and the format don't even closely match... Why do you even expect this to work?

Comment: i assigned the date time string to text just for understanding purpose here.In my scenario, The date string comes from datetimepicker picker control.

Comment: This question shows a lack of research thus the reason for my downvote. Your date contains `/` and you are attempting to parse a date that includes `-` the two strings will never match. You are also trying to parse the **2-digit-day**-**Month**-4 digit year which isn't a valid date. If what you posted is only an example its best to make sure the example is VALID.

Comment: If you work with a datetimepicker, why do you have to parse a string and not use the `.value` which should already be a `DateTime`?

Comment: if it shows lack of research work, then why am getting lot of response here?  i stuck, i asked. now i got an answer. are you trying to say that the question i asked wont help anyone in future. well it helpefd me and the others who answered.

Comment: Effort of others (responding) does not mean *you* showed any effort (doing research on your own). Also, even if it will help others in the future, it is still a "bad" question in the sense that SO tries to encourage research first, asking here second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";

string timeFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

note: passing `null` to `ParseExact` will make parser to take current culture, which may work differently on different environments. If you have strict format, pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` thus making parser to behave identically on all environments

single `d` will work for zero-padded days in date, as well as `M` and `h`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the following format string: `"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";
string timeFormat = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

runs for me. Note that the `dd` might be `d` depending on whether your days are zero padded.

Answer (score 3):

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)*;

> **The format of the string representation must match the specified
>   format exactly.**

Try like this;

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";
string timeFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/TTUjnS).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string timeFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";
string timeFormat = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it so hard?

```
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(text);

//dt = {2013-05-17 20:08:48}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the format for "PM"(tt); it should be:

```
try{
string text = "5/17/2013 8:08:48 PM";

string timeFormat = "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";

DateTime.ParseExact(text,timeFormat,null); 

}   catch (FormatException) { ... }
```

Note that you should always handle this exception when using this method.

Comment: why not to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` then?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yes I ussualy use TryParseExact; but I think it's more readable the try catch blocks; instead of explaining a new method. And note that you won't get any exception so you will have to test the boolean returned by TryParseExact.